# Filter only if the value is defined in Django

Tags: python, django, post

I have the following view:

```
def process(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        results = Specs.objects.filter(screenGroup = data['screen_user'], storage = data['storage_user'], mSystem = data['system_user'] )
        context = {'results' : results}
        return render(request, 'process.html', context)
```

When the user inputs the three values it filters correctly, but when it just inputs one or two (or nothing), then it filters passing the value None. Is there any way to ignore the filter if it's not set?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The following code is working, but it's obviously a very unefficient way:

```
def process(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       data = request.POST
       if(data['screen_user'] != None):
           results = Specs.objects.filter(screenGroup = data['screen_user'])
        elif (data['storage_user'] != None):
           results = Specs.objects.filter(storage = data['storage_user'])
        else:
           results = Specs.objects.all()
           #plus all the other options...
        context = {'results' : results}
        return render(request, 'process.html', context)
```

Comment: Are you not doing a form submit ?

Comment: Nope, I'm passing the data via AJAX (jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the filter beforehand:

```
def process(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST
        spec_filter = {}
        for attribute in ['screenGroup', 'storage', 'mSystem']:
            if attribute in data and data[attribute]:
                spec_filter[attribute] = data[attribute] 
        results = Specs.objects.filter(**spec_filter)
        context = {'results' : results}
        return render(request, 'process.html', context)
```

**NB**: To use this verbatim you would have to change the names of the variables being passed in the request.POST to match those in the `Specs` model. I did this just to illustrate, but you can easily use the same principle with your variable names. In that case you'll have to be a bit more verbose.

Comment: It worked fine, by the way, I will investigate all the form validation issue in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's called [validating your form.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/). There are two ways of doing this:

1. create a django form and use myform.is_valid(). You can read about it [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/)
2. validate it yourself with a few 'if' statements (either on server side or with javascript before sending the ajax call)

Comment: I understand that I have to change my form too, haven't I?